# $H^1$ of a certain line bundle on the resolution of  a 2-dimensional hypersurface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X = (f=0) \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ 
be an isolated hypersurface singularity and 
$\mu: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be a resolution of a singularity whose exceptional locus $E$ is simple normal crossing. Then

**Question** Is $H^1(\tilde{X}, \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(- E)) =0$ ?

I think it's OK if it is Du Bois. How about in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is a seminormal surface, then actually this vanishing is equivalent to $X$ being Du Bois:

1. If $X$ is Du Bois, the vanishing is a direct consequence of Cor.6.2 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-51/issue-1/Du-Bois-pairs-and-vanishing-theorems/10.1215/0023608X-2010-020.full), but in this case it is actually pretty easy to prove directly, see #2.
2. Let $P\in X$ be the singular point. There is a standard distinguished triangle
   $$ \underline\Omega_X^0 \to \mathscr O_P \oplus R\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}\to R\mu_*\mathscr O_E\overset{+1}\to.$$

See 4.11 of [Du Bois's paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1981__109__41_0) for this.
It is easy to see (or use Lemma 2.1 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2010-23-03/S0894-0347-10-00663-6/home.html)) that this implies that there exists a distinguished triangle
$$R\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}(-E)\to \underline\Omega_X^0 \to \mathscr O_P\overset{+1}\to$$

Now observe that $h^0(\underline\Omega_X^0)$ is the seminormalization of $\mathscr O_X$ and
the outside terms have no cohomology higher than $h^1$, so the only non-trivial map is
$$R^1\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}(-E)\to h^1(\underline\Omega_X^0)$$
This is an isomorphism, because $\mathscr O_P$ has very little cohomology. It follows that $X$ is Du Bois if and only if $R^1\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}(-E)=0$. $\quad\square$

**Remark** It is essential in this proof that $X$ is a surface. In higher dimensions it is true that Du Bois implies the desired vanishing, but I don't think the opposite implication holds. See #1 and my second comment below.

Comment: Just a quick comment, Steenbrink's paper *Mixed hodge structures and isolated singularities* also studies this condition a little (in fact, it is very close to how Steenbrink interpreted Du Bois singularities).

Comment: Karl, yes. At first I thought of just quoting Steenbrink, but I don't think he explains why, just kind of says that it's true. I thought it might be more useful if I explain the simple proof.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quite helpful answer. Actually, I was reading that paper of Steenbrink a bit and I couldn't find the condition on $H^1$ is necessary and sufficient to be Du Bois. Maybe I should learn more. 

Comment: Steenbrink says that for an isolated normal singularity being Du Bois is equivalent to the restriction maps $R^i\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}\to R^i\mu_*\mathscr O_E$ being isomorphisms for all $i>0$. In the case of a surface this is equivalent to the vanishing of $R^1\mu_*\mathscr O_{\widetilde X}(-E)$. 